# Side menu sticked

Tags: javascript

Not sticked left side menu from top of the div.

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftCol">
  <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
    <li><a href="#sec0">Section 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec2">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec3">Section 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec4">Section 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$('#sidebar').affix({
  offset: { top: 245 }
});

var $body   = $(document.body);
var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 10;

$body.scrollspy({
  target: '#leftCol',
  offset: navHeight
});
```

[image]

Comment: please provide full code you have tried so that we can check proper else provide example link of your code..

Comment: have it `position: fixed` with new `top` value when you need it to stick. best way - create a css class, that has that style. and add that class when scrolled down. remove, when scrolled back up.